# Display Fibonnaci Sequence less than or equal to an input number in a flask app within a URL endpoint

Tags: python, url, flask, endpoint

I am using a flask app and url endpoint to allow the input of a number. I then want to display the fibonnaci sequence up until it is equal to or less than the inputted number.

This is what I currently have:

```
@app.route("/fibonacci/<int:param_fi>/")
def getFib(param_fi):
if param_fi < 2:
    return ('0,1,1')
else:
    L = getFib(param_fi-1)
    if L[-1] < param_fi:
        L.append(L[-1] + L[-2])
    return L
```

I am having trouble pinpointing exactly where the error is from. I have tried making a list and converting it to strings but can't ever get it to work. When I try this it returns the following error: 
"The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list."

I am looking for the following output:

/fibonacci/250(this is the user input)/

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233
```

Or  /fibonacci/90(this is the user input)/

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Final**

```
@app.route("/fibonacci/<int:param_fi>/")
def getFib(param_fi):
    i = 0
    j = 1
    sequence = []
    current_operation = 0
    index = 0
    while True:
        sequence.append(i)
        current_operation = i + j
        i = j
        j = current_operation
        if i > param_fi:
            return json.dumps(sequence)
        else:
            index += 1
    return json.dumps(sequence)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand the error, can you output the result you want to have ? Do you need recursive like you did or no ?

But I guess you are missing something? You only return 0 or 1, or sum of both, so yes, you will never have the full sequence of the fibonacci.

You need to keep in memory the sequence, or return a list and adding elements each time, at least.

**EDIT**
https://repl.it/@skapin/AcceptableFoolishAssemblylanguage

```
def fibo(params):
  i = 0
  j = 1
  sequence = []
  current_operation = 0
  for current_n in range(0, params+1):
    # We appends now, since f(0) = 0 = i_initial , f(1) = 1 =j_initial
    sequence.append(i)
    # prepare next opération
    current_operation = i + j
    i = j
    j = current_operation

  return sequence

print(fibo(10))
```

**EDIT2-Flask**

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/fibonacci/<int:param_fi>/")
def get_fibo(param_fi):
    return jsonify(fibo(param_fi))
```

**Final**

```
from flask import jsonify
def fibo(params):
  i = 0
  j = 1
  sequence = []
  current_operation = 0
  index = 0
  while True:
    # We appends now, since f(0) = 0 = i_initial , f(1) = 1 =j_initial
    sequence.append(i)
    # prepare next opération
    current_operation = i + j
    i = j
    j = current_operation
    # Stop condition
    if i > params:
      return sequence
    else:
      index += 1

  return sequence


@app.route("/fibonacci/<int:param_fi>/")
def get_fibo(param_fi):
    return jsonify(fibo(param_fi))
```

Comment: Updated with latest try, added desired output. No it does not need to be recursive.

Comment: It is throwing an error saying "current operation = 0" is invalid syntax

Comment: Did you try it online ?

Comment: on the code you past, you forgot the _underscore_ between current/operation

Comment: Ohh okay, I fixed that and got the code to run. But now I get this error: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list".

Comment: So now, you need to know "how to return a list in flask". You can return a json for example, or a string of your list. Your choice

Comment: @DakotaBrown I edited my 1st response, test and tell us but it should be ok (but ain't tested it, no flask under my hand at the moment)

Comment: Okay so that worked, thank you! But returning n number of items in the sequence is not what I want to do. What I want to do is if the input is 50, then it will return all of the sequence numbers that are up to 50 but not go past it. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, it works well in the flask app now. That code just doesn't do exactly what I am trying to do with fibonnaci sequence.

Comment: @DakotaBrown I do understand, , it's my-bad I missread. I just added a stop condition, it should done the job, check and valid thanks :)

Comment: Okay I added the code I am using to the bottom of my original post. When I use the code you changed, it is returning an empty set of brackets like this - [ ]

Comment: You just failed at copy/pasta please, try to find the diference between the two code, you will se you forgot the             sequence.append(i)

Comment: Yes I did fail at copy pasta! Thank you so much for all the help!